# Kendo validator Custom rule for Required Field

Tags: jquery, validation, kendo-ui

I’m trying to use custom validation rules using kendo validator to make a textbox required only if a checkbox is selected. But this customRule1 is making all the fields in the form required when I click on submit button. Please help what I am missing?

```
var pilotType = document.getElementById("PilotType");
var validator = $("#frmAddDetails").kendoValidator({
            rules: {
                customRule1: function (input) {
                    if (input.is("[id = chkPilotPresent]").checked) {
                        pilotType.setAttribute("required", "required");

                    }

                }
            },
            errorTemplate: "<span></span>", 
            validate: function (e) { 
                var html = "";
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!e.valid) {
                    var errors = this.errors();
                    var requiredFieldCount = 0;
                    html += "<ul>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                        if (errors[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("required") > 0 && requiredFieldCount == 0) {
                            html += "<li> Please enter mandatory Fields *</li>";
                            requiredFieldCount++;## Heading ##                        }
                        else if (errors[i].toLowerCase().indexOf("required") < 0) {
                            html += "<li>" + errors[i] + "</li>";
                        }
                    }

                    html += "</ul>";
                }
                $("#errors").html($(html));
            }
        }).data("kendoValidator");
```